# How to open the doc file for a vim plugin?

Tags: vim, vim-plugins

I just downloaded the Rails vim plugin from [here](http://rails.vim.tpope.net/).

One of the file that it contain is a doc file that will be extracted to `~/.vim/doc/rails.txt`

How do I open the content of this help file in `vim` ?

I tried `:help rails` to no avail.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

After installing a new help file into ~/.vim/doc, you need to rebuild the help tags file:

```
:helptags ~/.vim/doc
```

Then your `:help rails` command should work.

Answer (score 5):

garyjohn's answer is right, but I just want to mention that [pathogen](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen) provides an easy way to run helptags for each plugin (note the case):

```
:Helptags
```